# Cannot read environment variables in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, environment-variables

In my Spring Boot apps, I generally pass environment variables to the `application.yml` via Run config of IntelliJ IDEA. However, I want to read these values from `.env` file and I tried the following approach:

***application.yml:***

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db_name}
    username: ${db_username}
    password: ${db_password}

  config:
    import: optional:file:.env[.properties] # I am trying to read the varables from `.env` file
```

And here is the `.env` file. Normally I keep it in the root of the project, but I temporarily move it to the same directory with `application.yml` to test if it could read:

```
db_name=test_db
db_username=postgres
db_password=123456
```

So, how can I read these variables from `application.yml` when running my Spring Boot app?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `${db.username}` or `${DB_USERNAME}`.